# file download from google drive to colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was trying to download file from my google drive to colaboratory.

```
file_id = '1uBtlaggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz'

import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  # _ is a placeholder for a progress object that we ignore.
  # (Our file is small, so we skip reporting progress.)
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()

downloaded.seek(0)
print('Downloaded file contents are: {}'.format(downloaded.read()))
```

doing so am getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'drive_service' is not defined
```

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 90):

**No installing/importing any library**. Just put your file id at the end.

```
!gdown yourFileIdHere
```

Note: at the time of writing gdown library is preinstalled on Colab.

Comment: Recently gdown has stopped functioning.

Comment: @AVISHEKGARAIN I've checked. It still works properly!

Comment: "Access denied with the following error:

  Cannot retrieve the public link of the file. You may need to change
 the permission to 'Anyone with the link', or have had many accesses. 

You may still be able to access the file from the browser:"

This is the error. The file is already publicly accessible. Tried with many files.

Comment: @AVISHEKGARAIN Apparently it's not a public problem. Open an issue in their github page if there's not already one addressing this error.

Comment: @AVISHEKGARAIN, I was having a similar problem because my file was too big and Google wanted to scan for viruses. I got around it by using this url and the id of the file:

`!wget file.csv 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXX&confirm=t'`

I think the `confirm=T` bypasses the virus.

Comment: Thanks @RossHochwert I wold definitely try it out.

Comment: Here `id` is what follows after /d/ in the link path. For instance in the following link drive.google.com/file/d/1q_wwOynOUCBmn51RJ3fxinLtuPF64ACg/view?usp=sharing , id is `1q_wwOynOUCBmn51RJ3fxinLtuPF64ACg`

Answer (score 22):

the easiest method to download a file from google drive to colabo notebook is via the colabo api:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

!cp '/content/gdrive/My Drive/<file_path_on_google_drive>' <filename_in_colabo>
```

Remarks:

1. By the drive.mount(), you can access any file on your google drive.
2. 'My Drive' is equivalent to 'Google Drive' on your local file system.
3. The file_path is surrounded with single quotes as the standard directory below the mount point ('My Drive') has a space, and you might also have spaces in your path elsewhere anyway.
4. Very useful to locate your file and get the file path is the file browser (activated by click on left arrow). It lets you click through your mounted folder structure and copy the file path, see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's an easy way to get by. You may either use wget command or requests module in Python to get the job done.

```
# find the share link of the file/folder on Google Drive
file_share_link = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_URf9ZWjAW7SC11Xzc4R2d0N2c"

# extract the ID of the file
file_id = file_share_link[file_share_link.find("=") + 1:]

# append the id to this REST command
file_download_link = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file_id
```

The string in `file_download_link` can be pasted in the browser address bar to get the download dialog box directly.

If you use the wget command:

```
!wget -O ebook.pdf --no-check-certificate "$file_download_link"
```

Answer (score 5):

**Step 1**

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
```

**Step 2**

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

**Step3**

```
file_id = '17Cp4ZxCYGzWNypZo1WPiIz20x06xgPAt' # URL id. 
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
downloaded.GetContentFile('shaurya.txt')
```

**Step4**

```
!ls #to verify content
```

OR

```
import os
print(os.listdir())
```

Comment: Especially for limited sharing files, this works very well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a drive API service client to interact with the Google drive API, for instance:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
```

(see the notebook [External data: Drive, Sheets, and Cloud Storage/Drive REST API](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=jRQ5_yMcqJiV))

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use Pydrive to download your file from google drive. I download 500MB dataset for 5s.
1. install Pydrive

```
!pip install PyDrive
```

2. OAouth

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

3. code for download file from google drive

```
fileId = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'DRIVE_FILE_ID'}) #DRIVE_FILE_ID is file id example: 1iytA1n2z4go3uVCwE_vIKouTKyIDjEq
print fileId['title']  # UMNIST.zip
fileId.GetContentFile('UMNIST.zip')  # Save Drive file as a local file
```

Cheer Mo Jihad

Answer (score 2):

For me, this works: `!gdown --fuzzy link_to_file -0 file.zip`

Answer (score 1):

The `--id` argument has been deprecated so now you simply have to run:

```
! gdown 1uBtlaggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
```

If your file is stored in a variable you can run:

```
! gdown $my_file_id
```

Answer (score 1):

For Files: `!gdown FileDrivePath`

For Folders: `!gdown --folder FolderDrivePath`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use my implementations on google.colab and PyDrive at https://github.com/ruelj2/Google_drive which makes it a lot easier.

```
!pip install - U - q PyDrive  
import os  
os.chdir('/content/')  
!git clone https://github.com/ruelj2/Google_drive.git  

from Google_drive.handle import Google_drive  
Gd = Google_drive()  
Gd.load_file(local_dir, file_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy all your google drive files and folders inside google colab and use it directly using this command

```
# import drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

This will ask you for permission after accepting you will have all your google drive inside your colab
If you want to use any file just copy the path