# How to run a Python script in a '.py' file from a Google Colab notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {
    return false;
}

%run rl_base.py
```

I run this giving error saying rl_base.py file not found. I have uploaded the same to gdrive in colab and from the same folder I am running my .ipynb file, containing the above code

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219341/is-it-possible-to-import-my-own-modules-into-a-google-colaboratory-notebook/49221494#49221494

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you have the test.py file in the corresponding folder in drive as in the below attached image, then the command which you use to run the test.py file is as mentioned below,

```
!python gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/object_detection_demo-master/test.py
```

#### Additional Info:

If you jusst want to run `!python test.py` then you should change directory, by the following command before it,

```
%cd gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/object_detection_demo-master/
```

[image: Folder Structure in Google Drive]

Answer (score 26):

When you run your notebook from Google drive, an instance is created only for the notebook. To make the other files in your Google drive folder available you can mount your Google drive with:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then copy the file you need into the instance with:

```
!cp gdrive/My\ Drive/path/to/my/file.py .
```

And run your script:

```
!python file.py
```

Answer (score 9):

You should not upload to gdrive. You should upload it to Colab instead, by calling

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

Comment: But what if I want to run a project and it has relative imports from directories present in the same folder?

Answer (score 6):

```
##  1. Check in which directory you are using the command
!ls
##  2.Navigate to the directory where your python script(file.py) is located using the command
%cd path/to/the/python/file
## 3.Run the python script by using the command
!python file.py
```

Comment: Please, improve formatting of your answer. Shell commands are not clear to catch.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple answer along with a screenshot

1. Mount the google drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2. Call the py file path

```
import sys
import os

py_file_location = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(py_file_location))
```

[image: Call y file in colab otebook]

Answer (score 1):

A way is also using [colabcode.](https://pypi.org/project/colabcode/). You will have full ssh access with Visual Studio Code editor.

```
# install colabcode
!pip install colabcode

# import colabcode
from colabcode import ColabCode

# run colabcode with by deafult options.
ColabCode()

# ColabCode has the following arguments:
# - port: the port you want to run code-server on, default 10000
# - password: password to protect your code server from being accessed by someone else. Note that there is no password by default!
# - mount_drive: True or False to mount your Google Drive

!ColabCode(port=10000, password="abhishek", mount_drive=True)
```

It will prompt you with a link to visual studio code editor with full access to your colab directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems necessary to put the .py file's name in ""
`!python "file.py"`