# python3: can't open file 'drive/My Drive/damage/custom.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am training Mask R-CNN on my own dataset and when I change runtime type in google colab to "GPU" the following error occurs

```
python3: can't open file 'drive/My Drive/damage/custom.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I change the runtime to "None" the training starts normally. How should I fix it?

Comment: Are you running in the correct directory? If not try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56095408/6232777)

Comment: No problem glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Save the file format as ".ipynb" and you would be able to load the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must mount Google drive first. After that you'll be able to access files from drive.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

PS: `content/gdrive` is no longer in use.

Answer (score 0):

When you change runtime type, you will loose or your mounted drives too, so you should mount your drive again and if you use local colab space, you should upload again your files.