# When I import a github code in google colab, the folders are not recognized and the modules cannot be imported

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I want to import [this code](https://github.com/klicperajo/ppnp) from github to google colab notebook. I used [this method](https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/notebooks/colab-github-demo.ipynb) and used [github address for google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/klicperajo/ppnp/blob/master/simple_example_pytorch.ipynb). But none of the folders in the project is recognized and any module from the folder next to the main code cannot be imported.

Answer (score 2):

Colab supports the opening of .ipynb files from Github, not entire Github repositories. As a result, you can only open one notebook at a time.

However, you can import custom libraries from Github into your Colab notebook, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219341/is-it-possible-to-import-my-own-modules-into-a-google-colaboratory-notebook?rq=1). In short, you'll need to run `!pip install git+https://github.com/klicperajo/ppnp`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the mentioned code in the first cell of the main ipynb file, but in the next cell, it still says that "No module named 'ppnp.pytorch'", am I doing something wrong?