# ModuleNotFoundError in Python - Colab

Tags: python, networking, networkx, google-colaboratory, pymnet

I am trying to implement a simple multi-layer network in colab using python. To do so, I ran the following code.

#### Code

```
from pymnet import *

mnet = MultilayerNetwork(aspects=1)
mnet.add_node(1)
mnet.add_layer('a')

mnet[1,'a'].deg()
```

However, I keep getting the following error.

#### Error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-74cefa95e553> in <module>()
----> 1 from pymnet import *
      2 mnet = MultilayerNetwork(aspects=1)
      3 mnet.add_node(1)
      4 mnet.add_layer('a')
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymnet'
```

Any suggestions with regard to how I could overcome this error will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that `pymnet` module is not in Colaboratory. You can download it from [pymnet source](https://bitbucket.org/bolozna/multilayer-networks-library/src/default/), then either [use it from your drive folder](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12qC2abKAIAlUM_jNAokGlooKY-idbSxi) or use the [other tricks suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49219341/is-it-possible-to-import-my-own-modules-into-a-google-colaboratory-notebook), to upload it to your colab space. [Some examples for other libraries](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb) provided by colab can help too.

Comment: @ilike444, unfortunately the link for downloading the module is not working anymore