# What is the path of the file uploaded to google drive using google-colaboratory?

Tags: python, path, google-colaboratory

I run this code on google colab to get the output shown below

```
import os
os.chdir("/content/drive/")
!ls
```

output

```
Convolutional_Neural_Networks.zip
```

However I don't see this zip file in my drive.Can someone help me out with the path where I can see this file in drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you upload are not stored in your google drive. It's saved in separate environment for colaboratory notebooks. If you want to use a file from drive or write file to drive. You'll have to install pyDrive in notebook environment and use it's functions. You can read more about it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive)

Comment: Oh Okay. Thank you.