# How to open txt on Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have my iris.txt stored at my Google Drive at My Drive/ML, I was trying to open and read it.

```
import csv
import numpy

file = open(r"/drive/ML/iris.txt")
mylist = list(csv.reader(file))
lines = numpy.asarray(mylist)
```

It returned me the error, how should I do?

```
IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-5be95fc15074> in <module>()
      6 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
      7 
----> 8 file = open(r"/my drive/ML/iris.txt")
      9 mylist = list(csv.reader(file))
     10 lines = numpy.asarray(mylist)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/my drive/ML/iris.txt'
```

Comment: You should retrieve the file from Google drive to a local folder where you could read it from. Check [Google doc for Drive](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/drive/v2)

Comment: I uploaded it from a local folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Colab: how to read data from my google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
from `google.colab` import files

uploaded = files.upload()

import io

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['ex1data1.csv']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

for f in uploaded.keys():
    file = open(f, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.