# Trouble loading data from Google Drive in Colaboratory

Tags: python, dataset, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load some data from google drive to my colab notebook, but I am getting an empty list.

*Code:*

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import glob
import os

test_path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/ML/data/cifar-100/test'

#path = os.path.join(test_path, 'class1', '*.jpg')
#path = os.path.join(test_path, 'class1', '*g')
path = os.path.join(test_path, 'class1', '*.*')

files = glob.glob(path)
len(files)
```

*Output*: 0

**Data**

[image]

[image]

Can anybody tell me why it’s not loading, everything seems to be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mounted your drive to `/content/drive` but in your test path you are using `/content/gdrive` which will not work. You need to use `/content/drive/My drive/...`

```
test_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/ML/data/cifar-100/test'
```

See [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA) for more info.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Codelt I don't deserve to live.

Comment: @arush1836 Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447199/3091398) person also don't deserve to live.