# Google colab Could not find directory (My Drive)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, drive

Error when i want to use a file from driv in colab

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

and them

```
INPUT_DIRECTORY='/content/drive/My Drive/deepcumbia/data/xml'
```

error:

```
Could not find directory /content/drive/My/
```

Comment: See this [Google Colab: how to read data from my google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive/53592023)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the space.

```
INPUT_DIRECTORY='/content/drive/My\ Drive/deepcumbia/data/xml'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is to add another way which worked for me, i.e. double check the actual directory path in colab.

When debugging this same issue, I noticed Google Colab takes the Google Drive default directory a bit different.
E.g. in Google Colab, the directory looked like this, there is no space in the word "MyDrive":

[image]

But when I browsed to the Google Drive, noticed there is a space in "My Drive":
[image]

So, for my case, I changed from:

```
sth= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Datasets/xyz.csv', index_col='abc')
```

to

```
sth= pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Datasets/xyz.csv', index_col='abc')
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues before too. This problem comes up when there is **space** in the link or path.

Thus, here's the **universal solution** : add a \ before the space.

So, if it's `dir = 'My Drive'`, change it to `dir = 'My\ Drive'`.

It will always work.

Moreover, here's the solution to your problem:

```
INPUT_DIRECTORY='/content/drive/My\ Drive/deepcumbia/data/xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be obvious but I had a typo, and it was solved by right clicking on my directory and selecting "Copy Path"