# Running in Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch

Good evening.
I want to run my python program on Google collab, but in what place I should download files and when open in python file?
How do I open this file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always upload files to `Google colab` and you can create a `directory` as well.

You can create a directory named `data`

[image]

And then upload the files which you want to be placed in the directory as shown below.

[image]

*** Remember the data uploaded or created during runtime will not be saved ***

Alternatively, you can save the files to your google drive and mount the drive
->
[Google Colab: how to read data from my google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive/56034635#56034635) to save your runtime files and folder directly to the drive.