# Is there any limitations for google colab other than the session timeout after 12 hours?

Tags: tensorflow, session, gpu, google-colaboratory, tpu

one of the limitations is that we can get only 12 continuous hours per session. Is there any limitations for the usage for GPU and TPU?

Comment: The limitations are in terms of RAM, GPU RAM and HBM, dependent on Google Colab hardware, at the moment is respectively ≈25GB, ≈12GB and ≈64GB. This will limit the dataset you can load in memory and the batch size in your training process.

Comment: Hello! Can I upload my whole project to google colab and run it from there please or it only accepts notebooks?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can only use 1 GPU with a limited memory of 12GB and TPU has 64 GB High Bandwidth Mmeory.You can read here in this [article](https://medium.com/@jannik.zuern/using-a-tpu-in-google-colab-54257328d7da).
So, if you want to use large dataset then I would recommend you to use `tf.data.Dataset` for preparing it before training.
If you want to use GPUs you can use any TF version. But for TPU I would recommend using TF1.14.

Comment: Is there any way to get the SIFT , SURF libraries in colab?

Comment: I think you can use it directly from `cv2`. Check this Colab [file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p7McfxQdXSD32KO3jPFigejiiTQjKivp).

Comment: Can I upload my project to Google colab please? I have a project with files and dataset, so how to load it there and run project?

Comment: @Avra Yes, you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive

Answer (score 7):

From Colab's documentation,

> In order to be able to offer computational resources for free, Colab needs to maintain the flexibility to adjust usage limits and hardware availability on the fly. Resources available in Colab vary over time to accommodate fluctuations in demand, as well as to accommodate overall growth and other factors.

In a nutshell, Colab has dynamic resource provisioning. So they can change the hardware, it it is being taxed too much automatically.
Google giveth and Google taketh away.

[Link](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)