# Save/Export a custom tokenizer from google colab notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, pickle

I have a custom tokenizer and want to use it for prediction in Production API. How do I save/download the tokenizer?

This is my code trying to save it:

```
import pickle
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

with file_io.FileIO('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

No error, but I can't find the tokenizer after saving it. So I assume the code didn't work?

Comment: Where are you saving? Where are you looking for it? What's your current working directory?

Comment: On google colab, so it should be in the G drive. But I try searching for it and couldn't find it.

Comment: G drive itself has subfolders, and it is not even the default directory when working in Colab. Please include the relevant info

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.... everything is automatically saved in G Drive by default. I searched the whole G Drive which includes all subfolders. I don't know what information to provide. How do you define the path to save it from? So my code is fine and you think the tokenizer is saved but hidden somewhere?

Comment: `My Drive > Colab Notebooks` This is the folder that all notebooks saved, automatically, I didn't define any path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the situation, using a simple file to disentangle the issue from irrelevant specificities like pickle, Tensorflow, and tokenizers:

```
# Run in a new Colab notebook:
%pwd
/content
%ls
sample_data/
```

Let's save a simple file `foo.npy`:

```
import numpy as np
np.save('foo', np.array([1,2,3]))

%ls
foo.npy  sample_data/
```

In this stage, `%ls` should show `tokenizer.pickle` in your case instead of `foo.npy`.

Now, Google Drive & Colab do not communicate by default; you have to [mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/google-colab-how-to-read-data-from-my-google-drive/52300696#52300696) the drive first (it will ask for identification):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Mounted at /content/drive
```

After which, an `%ls` command will give:

```
%ls
drive/  foo.npy  sample_data/
```

and you can now navigate (and save) inside `drive/` (i.e. actually in your Google Drive), changing the path accordingly. Anything saved there can be retrieved later.

Comment: Thanks desertnaut for the detailed response. It didn't solve the problem directly but led me to investigate further. The problem was that I was saving the file at the peer level of the drive, not inside it, that's why I couldn't find it in gdrive. I'll make it as answer. People who land here will be able to figure out reading our comments.