# How I can open text files in Colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I wanted to open a text file in my program, but it says it doesn't have that directory.

The program:

```py
f = open("09.txt")
print(f)
```

The problem:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-548362b34f47> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 f = open("09.txt")
      2 print(f)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '09.txt'
```

I put my file in the folder where my notebook is. I also tried to put it outside this folder but it didn't work too.
[File explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlJJm.png)

Comment: See `os.getcwd()` to check where the kernel started your Python session.

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data in Google Colab from my Google drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48376580/how-to-read-data-in-google-colab-from-my-google-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Colaboratory, the working directory might not be the same as the directory where your notebook is located. To open a file successfully, you need to specify the correct path to the file. You can use the os module to get the current working directory and then construct the full path to your file.

```py
import os

# Get the current working directory
current_directory = os.getcwd()

# Specify the file name
file_name = "09.txt"

# Construct the full path to the file
file_path = os.path.join(current_directory, file_name)

# Open the file
try:
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        # Do something with the file (e.g., print its contents)
        print(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"The file '{file_name}' was not found in the current directory.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

This code first gets the current working directory using os.getcwd(), then constructs the full path to your file using os.path.join(), and finally tries to open the file. If the file is not found, it will print a message indicating that the file was not found.

Make sure the file is in the same directory as your notebook or provide the correct path relative to the notebook's location. If you are still facing issues, double-check the file name and the directory structure. You can also use the file explorer in Colab to confirm the location of your notebook and the file.